Bash is incredibly slow when doing command substitution or piping
My Bash script is incredibly slow when doing command substitution or piping, am I missing something?
(I used to know Bash having a similar speed compared to Python or other interpreted languages or even be faster than them, except when calling external apps)
### My code
function a { true; }
echo -en '\n>>> a'
time for i in {0..100}; do a; done
echo -en '\n>>> echo'
time for i in {0..100}; do echo >/dev/null; done
echo -en '\n>>> (condition, variable assignment, arithmetic)'
time for i in {0..100}; do
  if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then
    var1=val1
    ((test++))
  fi
done
echo -en '\n>>> $(echo)'
time for i in {0..100}; do $(echo) >/dev/null; done
echo -en '\n>>> $(a)'
time for i in {0..100}; do $(a); done
echo -en '\n>>> `a`'
time for i in {0..100}; do `a`; done
echo -en '\n>>> echo | a'
time for i in {0..100}; do echo | a; done
echo -en '\n>>> a | echo'
time for i in {0..100}; do a | echo >/dev/null; done


### Acceptable operations
# a
0.001s

# echo
0.002s

# (condition, variable assignment, arithmetic)
0.001s


### Slow operations
# $(echo)
0.316s

# $(a)
0.315s

# `a`
0.315s

# echo | a
0.521s

# a | echo
0.518s


in the timed operations that make use of echo replace with /usr/bin/echo; you should see a significant difference in run times with echo (shell builtin) running faster than /usr/bin/echo (binary) that has an overhead for 'starting' the binary; as others have already mentioned in answers - opening/closing a subshell also incurs a noticeable (timing wise) overhead

"except when calling external apps". That's pretty much what you are timing here, forking new shells to execute the command substitutions and pipe components.

@chepner The problem is when you call even an internal function with piping or process substitution (to simply receive its response or do other basic works), it becomes tens or even hundreds of times slower and you have to look for an alternative method if the performance matters

Yeah, shells are slow, system-calls are slow.  Bash is slow amongst shells, but even a faster shell is still a shell so you'll still often write scripts that use external commands.
Use a different language like Perl or Python for string manipulation and fork/exec only for the few external commands you actually want to use.

This is all completely normal. People who are competent at writing efficient shell scripts work to avoid creating pipelines in inner loops, instead creating them on the outside and reusing them. Sloppily written shell scripts are slow shell scripts; writing efficient ones is an art.

@PeterCordes, "Use a different language... for string manipulations" can be deeply counterproductive if you're forking an interpreter for that string manipulation from a shell; using parameter expansion or other built-in mechanisms is often appropriate.

BTW, re: the duplicate -- remember that pipes and command substitutions fork off subshells (to replace that subshell with a separate executable via the execve syscall when requested, which of course adds its own additional overhead), so "why are subshells slow?" answers "why are pipelines slow?" and "why are command substitutions slow?".

@CharlesDuffy: Ok, to be clear, what I meant was write a #!/usr/bin/perl script, not fork perl from a #!/bin/bash script!  Perl makes a decent shell for gluing commands together, having my $output = \command`;` easy capture syntax, and you have its powers of string manipulation and easy looping over lines of strings and input streams.

@PeterCordes, OTOH, some of that "easy" syntax also makes it easy to have injection vulnerabilities; when you're using shell variables in a shell it won't parse them as syntax unless you explicitly use eval or some equivalent; when you're substituting perl syntax into strings passed to a shell, you don't get those protections.

@CharlesDuffy: That's a good point.  I usually write bash scripts with shell-builtin manipulation, or perl scripts that do everything themselves, not forking external commands. I've rarely actually done what I suggested and written perl scripts that captured command output.

("I used to know Bash having a similar speed compared to Python or other interpreted languages or even be faster than them" -- this was never true; even Python 1.x was much faster than shells contemporary to it; that said, that's true if you discard interpreter startup time; the place where you get benefits from doing things directly in a shell is the situation where that lets you avoid doing any fork/exec to start an external process)

@CharlesDuffy I'm okay with regular differences in speed (even 2x or more), but being, say, 100x slower in two of the most used syntaxes is kinda weird

@RezaAlizade, again, shells have always been this kind of slow. If you stop thinking about things like grep, cut, etc as functions the shell can call and instead think of them as completely separate programs (which they are), it should become intuitively obvious why that's true. Starting a cut executable with the subprocess module every time you want to calculate a substring would be crazy slow in Python, just as it's crazy slow (compared to in-process string operations) in shell -- starting subprocesses is slow by nature!

So just as nobody writing good Python would use subprocess.Popen(['cut', -c2-']).communicate(varname)[0] instead of varname[1:], nobody writing good shell should use printf '%s\n' "$varname" | cut -c2- instead of printf '%s\n' "${varname:1}"; they're equally horrible approaches from a performance perspective, it's just that your average person writing shell doesn't know any better, whereas your average person writing Python does.

(to be clear, there's additionally a large performance difference between a language having a bytecode interpreter that executes an instruction set built to be easy to operate on efficiently, and a language that's directly interpreting content from an ad-hoc parser; but that's minor compared to the difference between builtins and external executables doing the work)

I don't think there is any problem here. On my machine, I get "slow operations" about 30x slower than "acceptable operations".
It takes time for BASH to create a subshell, and to get the output in the parent shell.
If you want better subshell creation speed, you could check dash, a minimalist shell. I now get 20x slower instead of 30x.
You should not expect much more.
In your case, you are seeing mainly the time of subshell creation + termination, but if you run a longer command in substitution or pipe, that time will become negligible.

Yes it varies on different machines and I got about 100x when tested on another machine. BTW Even 30x is very slow considering that both piping and substitution are two basic and very popular operations in Bash and we have to keep this in mind when writing scripts with Bash.

@RezaAlizade, ...I wonder, idly, if the "another machine" in question was running Windows -- fork() is much slower / more expensive there than it is on systems with a more traditional Unix-y design.

@CharlesDuffy I didn't fully get you but that was a Red Hat machine. Also I tested again, it got 40x slower for substitution and about 75x slower for piping

Interesting. If you want to run down the "why" of that, what I've traditionally used for the purpose is OProfile, though it's getting a bit long in the tooth -- I wouldn't be surprised if there were modern eBPF-based replacements. Anyhow, pipes require more forks than simple command substitutions do since you have a separate process for each pipeline component, so it's completely normal that it's slower.
